# Replication / Staging error - The refresh of caches failed

Tags: intershop

Custom staging process that contains replication groups:

- predefined (tables Catalogs, Products, Promotions...)
- custom (one table A1MKWebPrice)

was working fine for months on daily basis.

Since the increase of data that is is imported in custom table A1MKWebPrice, replication process ends with status:

**86% - Error: The refresh of caches failed!**

---

ORM monitoring:

[image: ORM monitoring]

---

WebPriceBOCache - ObjectCacheGroup (Business Layer) defined in component framework:

[image: WebPrice CacheClearHandler]

I have cleared cache numerous ways in WebPriceBORepository after import of price:

```
LRUHashMap<String, Collection<WebPriceBO>> cache.clear();
webPricePOFactory.getEngine().getCacheManager().clearCache();
```

That clears Loaded (103.881 to 0) persistent objects A1MKWebPricePO but Count stays (103.884).

If i understand correctly cached persistent objects are in the JVM memory of an application server and they can not be controlled (deleted).

Should i somehow clear cache of persistent objects or increase JVM memory?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm always a bit hesitant to increase memory size, cpu power or anything, as this is probably only a temporary solution: could you maybe check what Processor is being used and if that is the correct processor? For example: you might be using FullDomainSpecificStagingProcessor but maybe DeleteAppendDomainSpecificStagingProcessor is sufficient and would, imho, be more efficient.
Also please check your clearCache method, are you clearing cache for all PersistentObjectPOKeys? Isn't that nearly everything?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think you should go to Intershop Support with that question.